# ¿Cómo acceder desde javascript a un element ul li cuanto tengo varios con sql?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, eventos

```
    echo "<div id='contenedor_central' class='contenedor_central'>";
$conexion=mysqli_connect("***", "***", "***", "***");

if(!$conexion){
    echo "La conexion ha fallado : " . mysqli_error();
    exit();
}

$tamano_paginas=6;

if(isset($_GET["pagina"])){
    if($_GET["pagina"]==1){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        $pagina=$_GET["pagina"];
    }
}else{
    $pagina=1;      
}

$empezar=($pagina-1)*($tamano_paginas);

$consulta="SELECT * FROM contenidoblog";

if($resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)){

    $num_filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    $total_paginas=ceil($num_filas/$tamano_paginas);
}

$consulta_filtrada="SELECT * FROM contenidoblog LIMIT $empezar, $tamano_paginas";
$resultado1=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_filtrada);

    if($resultado1){

        while($registro= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado1)){  
            echo "<div class='opciones'>
                    <ul class='menu_noticia desactivado'>
                        <li>Favoritos</li>
                        <li>Compartir</li>
                        <li>Me gusta</li>
                        <li>Comentar</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>";
            echo "<div id='cajaContenedor' style='width:40%; height:auto; margin-left:30%; display: flex;'> ";

            if($registro['imagen']!=""){
                echo "<img style='border-radius: 5px;  text-align:center;display:table-cell; background-position: center center; padding:2px; width:auto;   height: auto; width: auto; max-width: 180px; max-height: 180px; min-width: 180px; min-height: 180px;' src='imagenes/" . $registro['imagen'] . "'  />";
            }

            echo"<div id='contenedor_titular_cabecera' style=' padding-left:4px; float:left; display:block; width:100%; '> <i id='btnn' class='boton_opciones fa fa-bars fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            <a method='post' style='color:black; text-decoration:none;' href='http://localhost/BLOG_ELESPECULADOR/template_noticias.php?".$registro['cabecera']."&id=".$registro['id']."'>";
            echo "<p style='text-align:left; margin-top:0px;'> ". $registro['fecha'] ."</p>";
            echo "<H2 style='   font-family: Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif;text-align:left;'>" . $registro['cabecera'] . "</H2>";
            echo "<p style='font-size:18px; font-family: Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif; Font being rendered:georgia; font-size: 15px; text-align:left; color:#707070;'>". $registro['titular'] . "</p>";

            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";


            echo "</div>";

        }


    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);

    for($i=1;$i<=$total_paginas;$i++){
        echo "<a href='?pagina=". $i . "'/>" . $i . "</a>  ";
    }
    echo "<BR></BR>";

echo "</div>";
```

El script es éste:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 



$("#contenedor_central .boton_opciones").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#contenedor_central .menu_noticia").addEventListener;
         if ($(this).hasClass('desactivado')){
             alert("HEY");
            $(this).css({"display":"table"});
            $(this).removeClass('desactivado');
            $(this).addClass('activado');
         }else{
            $(this).removeClass('activado');
            $(this).css({"display":"table"});
            $(this).removeClass('activado');
            $(this).addClass('desactivado');
         }
    });
 });
```

El problema está en que cuando le doy al icono para mostrar el ul, se me muestran todos los ul de todos los divs, y yo solo quiero que se muestre el que he clicado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si el botón boton_opciones está por fuera del ul como sabes a cual ul has seleccionado ? no entiendo !

Comment: Lo que se puede hacer es determinar que `li` fue clickeado en la lista. Además no se entiende porque pones `$(this).css({"display":"table"});` tanto sea cierto como falso el `if`, para eso lo pones afuera o en el CSS mismo.

Comment: La idea es que yo pueda pincharle a un icono(que es como un boton) y me muestre el ul que actualmente tiene display none;

Comment: en lugar de php mejor incluye el html que sea relevante, eso te lo copias directo de la página

Comment: el php es lo relevante, porque necesito hacer una funcion y nose como hacerla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haría sería añadir un padre para cada elemento `menu_noticia` y `cajaContenedor`, con el fin de que puedan ser hermanos directos sin que interfieran el resto de elementos y poder hacer un script que detecte cual es el `ul` que pertenece a la "familia" de elementos del botón al cual se le dio click

```
<!-- Inicio de while -->
<div class="contenedor_item">
    <div class='opciones'>
        <ul class='menu_noticia desactivado'>
            <li>Favoritos</li>
            <li>Compartir</li>
            <li>Me gusta</li>
            <li>Comentar</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='cajaContenedor' style='width:40%; height:auto; margin-left:30%; display: flex;'> 
        <img style='border-radius: 5px;  text-align:center;display:table-cell; background-position: center center; padding:2px; width:auto;   height: auto; width: auto; max-width: 180px; max-height: 180px; min-width: 180px; min-height: 180px;' src=''  />

        <div id='contenedor_titular_cabecera' style=' padding-left:4px; float:left; display:block; width:100%; '> 
            <i id='btnn' class='boton_opciones fa fa-bars fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            <a method='post' style='color:black; text-decoration:none;' href='http://localhost/BLOG_ELESPECULADOR/template_noticias.php'>
            <p style='text-align:left; margin-top:0px;'></p>
            <H2 style='   font-family: Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif;text-align:left;'></H2>
            <p style='font-size:18px; font-family: Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif; Font being rendered:georgia; font-size: 15px; text-align:left; color:#707070;'></p>

            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fin de while -->

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#contenedor_central .boton_opciones").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var elemento = $(this).parents('.contenedor_item').find('.menu_noticia');

        $(elemento).css({"display":"table"});

        if ($(elemento).hasClass('desactivado')){
             alert("HEY");
            $(elemento).removeClass('desactivado');
            $(elemento).addClass('activado');
        }else{
            $(elemento).removeClass('activado');  
            $(elemento).removeClass('activado');
            $(elemento).addClass('desactivado');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos maneras de hacerlo. La más fácil, a mi gusto, es que cada uno de tus elementos `cajaContenedor` tenga su propio `ul` de opciones. De esa manera, al activar `.boton_opciones` puede dirigirse a su propio "hermano" (en el sentido que pertenecen al mismo parent).

En el siguiente ejemplo reemplacé algunos IDs por clases porque en tu código estarías repitiendo IDs por cada resultado y eso es incorrecto. Me tomé la libertad de ponerle algunos estilos.

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("#contenedor_central .boton_opciones").click(function(e){
          // acá el botón opciones encuentra el "menú noticia" de su mismo contenedor.
          var $menu_noticia= jQuery(this)
          .closest('.cajaContenedor')
          .find('.menu_noticia');
          
          if ( $menu_noticia.hasClass('desactivado')){
              $menu_noticia
                .removeClass('desactivado')
                .addClass('activado');
           }else{
               $menu_noticia
                .removeClass('activado')
                .addClass('desactivado');
           }
        });
      });
```

```css
#contenedor_central {
        width:100%
        height:100%;
        border:; 1px solid red;
      }   
      .cajaContenedor {
        border-bottom: 1px solid; 
        margin-bottom:10px;
        width:40%; 
        height:auto; 
        margin-left:30%; 
        display: flex;
        float:left;
      }
      .cajaContenedor h2 {
        font-family: Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif;
        text-align:left;
        color:blue;
      }
      .fecha {
        text-align:left; margin-top:0px;
      }
      .contenedor_titular_cabecera {
        padding-left:4px; float:left; display:block; width:100%;
      }
      .menu_noticia {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
      }
      .menu_noticia.activado {
        display:table;
      }
      .titular {
        font-size:18px; 
        font-family: Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif; 
        font-size: 15px; 
        text-align:left;
        color:#707070;
      }
      .opciones {
        position:relative;
        float:right;

      }
      .boton_opciones {
        float:right;
      }
      .arrow-down {
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top: 8px solid #f00;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:0;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <div id='contenedor_central' class='contenedor_central'>
    
    <div class='cajaContenedor' >
        <div class='contenedor_titular_cabecera'>
          <div class='opciones'>
           <span class='boton_opciones fa fa-bars fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'>Opciones  <i class="arrow-down"></i>
            </span>
                <ul class='menu_noticia desactivado'>
                  <li>Favoritos</li>
                  <li>Compartir</li>
                  <li>Me gusta</li>
                  <li>Comentar</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <p class="fecha">fecha1</p>
            <h2>titulo1</h2>
            <p class="titular">Contenido 1</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
        <div class='cajaContenedor' >
        <div class='contenedor_titular_cabecera'>
          <div class='opciones'>
           <span class='boton_opciones fa fa-bars fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'>Opciones  <i class="arrow-down"></i>
            </span>
                <ul class='menu_noticia desactivado'>
                  <li>Favoritos</li>
                  <li>Compartir</li>
                  <li>Me gusta</li>
                  <li>Comentar</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <p class="fecha">fecha2</p>
            <h2>titulo2</h2>
            <p class="titular">Contenido 2</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Tendrías que adaptar el html de tu script PHP para generar ese tipo de bloques HTML.

Hay otra opción en donde agregas sólo un bloque de `.menu_noticia` (y esto se haría afuera del loop `while`) y al pinchar en `.menu_opciones` inserta temporalmente el bloque `.menu_noticia` dentro del contenedor que acabas de pinchar. Pero como las opciones para actuar sobre cada post estarían vinculadas a su ID, además de modificar el DOM tendrías que modificar los links asociados a Favoritos, Compartir, etc al momento de meter ese contenedor en el contenedor del artículo. Puede que esto sea sobreoptimizar.

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar el objeto al que se le ha dado click con jquery, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);

function clickHandler(e) {

  var tg = $(e.target);

  if ( tg.hasClass('boton_opciones') ) { // o como identifiques lo que quieres
    if (tg.hasClass('desactivado')) {
      // Lo activas, etc...
    } else {
      // Lo desactivas, etc...
    }
  }
}
```